# Rails- upgrading to ruby 2.2.2 - no implicit conversion of Array into String (TypeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

very new to ruby and rails.. Ive been working on a project, that simply reads in files and parses them to store into a database. Project was running fine, however running the code after an update to ruby 2.2.2 , I received an error that wasn't previously there:

```
in `foreach': no implicit conversion of Array into String (TypeError)
```

Here is the snippet of the `foreach` thats causing an error: (let me know if more code is necessary).

```
def parse(file_name)
  File.foreach(file_name).with_index do |line, line_num|
    puts "\nLine #{line_num}: #{line}"
```

Does anyone know whats going on?
Thank you

EDIT: Sorry it was a snippet! Im calling this ruby code into my rails Test called "parse_log_file_test"

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../test_helper'

class ParseLogFileTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  filename = Array.new

  Dir.glob('database/oag-logs/*.log').each do |log_file|

    filename.push(log_file)

  end

  parser = ParseLogFile.new

  parser.parse(filename)

  test 'parse' do
    parser = ParseLogFile.new

    filename.each do |log_file|

      begin

        parser.parse(log_file)
      rescue

        puts"ERROR: Unable to parse line #{log_file}"

      end
    end
    assert true
  end
end
```

Comment: what does the call to parse(file_name) look like?

Comment: What Ruby version were you migrating from?

Comment: migrating from version 2.1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently this is an issue with upgrading to ruby 2.2.2 on windows. After getting past this error, I only encountered more errors.. nokogiri..etc

I have recently got a mac and the errors went away.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you omitted the `end` to your function, but if you don't have it, you need it.

Comment: sorry it was a snippet! the file itself is longer. I forgot to add that I'm calling this ruby file into my rails test which looks like this

Comment: @KennyEllis Add this code to your question (i.e. edit the question to contain it) rather than putting it into a comment. It will be much easier to read there.

Comment: thanks for the insight! That makes a lot more sense!

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates that the argument passed to `parse` as `file_name` is an array instead of a string.

However, if that's the case, it fails the same on e.g. Ruby 1.8.4:

```
File.foreach([]).with_index do |line, line_num|
  puts "\nLine #{line_num}: #{line}"
end
```

Output:

```
TypeError: can't convert Array into String
    from (irb):1:in `foreach'
    from (irb):1:in `with_index'
    from (irb):1
    from :0
```

<del>Thus my guess is that the code that produces the value you pass to `parse` returned a string in your previous Ruby version and returns an array in 2.2.2.</del>

In your case, the error is caused by the first invocation of `parser.parse(...)`, right above the `test 'parse' do` line, not by the invocation inside the test method. I guess you put that invocation there *after* the migration, probably to debug a problem. But you are passing a different argument to the first invocation than to the invocation inside the test method, so it fails for a different reason than the one in the test method.

To see what Error is caused inside your test, simply remove the lines

```
      rescue

        puts"ERROR: Unable to parse line #{log_file}"
```

(Keep the `end` or you'll have to remove the `begin`, too.)

This way, an Error will hit the test runner, which will usually display it including message and stack trace.

Comment: Unfortunately after commenting out puts ERROR and rescue the same error is present.

Comment: You must also remove the first `parser.parse(filename)`. (The one outside the `test 'parse' do`block.)

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with the poster above that you are most likely missing quotation marks. It should have nothing to do with 2.2.2 though, probably you are copy-pastying your file name differently this time around.

Comment: It didn't have to do with copy and pasting or the quotation marks

Comment: Turns out it was an problem with windows running ruby 2.2.2